# Json.net serialize numeric properties as string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using JsonConvert.SerializeObject to serialize a model object.
The server expects all fields as strings. My model object has numeric properties and string properties. I can not add attributes to the model object. Is there a way to serialize all property values as if they were strings? I have to support only serialization, not deserialization.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475997/convert-int-to-string-while-serialize-object-using-json-net

Comment: @CodeJoy: That seems pretty DataTable-focused to me - I can't see how any of those answers are going to help the OP.

Comment: See [Convert long number as string in the serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369278/convert-long-number-as-string-in-the-serialization).

Comment: Sorry @CodeJoy, but I was thinking of something "more automatic",  like a ContractResolver or something like this. I wouldn't like to convert manually my model object into a JObject with all properties as strings. I will use this solution as a last resource, cause it works. Anyway thank you for your help!! ;)

Comment: @dbc Tested and works like a charm. Perfect!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can provide your own `JsonConverter` even for numeric types. I've just tried this and it works - it's quick and dirty, and you almost certainly want to extend it to support other numeric types (`long`, `float`, `double`, `decimal` etc) but it should get you going:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Model
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

}

internal sealed class FormatNumbersAsTextConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;
    public override bool CanConvert(Type type) => type == typeof(int);

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        int number = (int) value;
        writer.WriteValue(number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type type, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var model = new Model { Count = 10, Text = "hello" };
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        { 
            Converters = { new FormatNumbersAsTextConverter() }
        };
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, settings));
    }
}
```