# Convert int to string JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json.net

I trying to convert a Table to JSON using Newtonsoft 
The main problem I have is that the values comes in different data types, so the INT does not return as a string.

Is there a simple way to do it? or do I have to look at the examples where you create custom converter?

```
dynamic data = table.CreateDynamicInstance();

var jsonBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

_settings.Request.AddParameter("application/json", jsonBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

jsonBody returns...

```
{"phone":555555,"email":"john.doe@svea.com"}
```

but should return...

```
{"phone":"555555","email":"john.doe@svea.com"}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to return strings, set the type to string...?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39526179/4685428) helps?

Comment: "_Is there a simple way to do it? or do I have to look at the examples where you create custom converter?_" Well, unless you can make `table.CreateDynamicInstance();` return objects with string fields/properties instead of numeric fields/properties, you have to use a custom JsonConverter...

Comment: Please show what you've tried, because if the type of a property is `string`, `JsonConvert` will output it as a quoted string.

Comment: That said (as addition to my former comment), i feel that using a custom JsonConverter would be better in any case. Why trying to change the behavior of `table.CreateDynamicInstance();` (which might possibly have further repercussions to other parts of your code working with the table and/or CreateDynamicInstance method)  just to accomodate the Json serializer? That doesn't make sense to me, since you can just keep this Json-related problem and its solution/fix local to the Json serialization process by using a custom JsonConverter...

Comment: @elgonzo yes thanks, it seems like that's the way to go!